# NavigatorKey not found on MaterialApp.router

Tags: flutter

Previously using `MaterialApp` there was a way to set a `GlobalContext` using a `NavigatorKey` located on the `MaterialApp widget`.

However now it's looks like that alternative is no longer possible, I have this structure, following `Navigator 2.0`

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        restorationScopeId: 'app',
        localizationsDelegates: const [
          AppLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
        onGenerateTitle: (BuildContext context) =>
            AppLocalizations.of(context)!.appTitle,
        routeInformationParser: const RoutemasterParser(),
        routeInformationProvider: routeInformationProvider,
        routerDelegate: introductionRouteMap(context, ref));
  }
```

Now there isn't any NavigatorKey. So my question is, how can I set a GlobalContext using `MaterialApp.router`?

Comment: How did you solve this? I have the same problem when i try to use Beamer and have to switch from MaterialApp to MaterialApp.router in my app.

Comment: How would one do the same thing but with Navigation?

Comment: Hi @Luis Did you find any solution to this? I came across this issue after I updated an app from old flutter version and now I am unable to navigate using named paths..

Answer (score 12):

You can add NavigatorKey in your RouterDelegate (Not tested). For those who are looking for GoRouter, navigatorKey can be added in the GoRouter constructor.

Answer (score 3):

if you just want a GlobalContext you can use `scaffoldMessengerKey` instead which  is used for showing snack bar.

Note: this `BuildContext` won't work for navigation

```
final scaffoldMessengerKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      scaffoldMessengerKey: scaffoldMessengerKey,
    );
  }
}
```

To access the global context

```
final context = scaffoldMessengerKey.currentContext!;
```

Comment: FYI: If you are trying to show an AlertDialog using this type of context, this will produce the error `Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.`.

Comment: @MatthewRideout yeah you are right, this won't work for navigation I will add this note to the answer.

Comment: How could I do the same thing but permit navigation?  Am using GoRouter and would like to provide context outside of the widget.

Comment: @MatthewRideout I have the reverse: I am using GoRouter without context but need to navigate to a specific route. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73059450/how-can-i-route-using-gorouter-in-flutter-without-context  Is that possible?

Comment: This helped me a lot since my main concern was to access App Localizations only, I didn't want to use it for navigation

Answer (score 3):

Here, you can declare the GlobalKey at the top of `main.dart` or any other location.

```
 final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

Then you can initialize this navigation key inside GoRouter like this:

```
...
static GoRouter routes = GoRouter(
navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
routes: [
  GoRoute(
...
```

Then you can use it like this.

```
 navigatorKey.currentState?.push(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Navigator 2.0 made Flutter's routing system more dynamic, but some information, previously passed in MaterialApp or CupertinoApp, has been removed, and it will be necessary to configure it using Modular's own support methods.

In your case, just add:

```
Modular.setNavigatorKey(myNavigatorKey);
```

Before  `MaterialApp.router()`

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative Solution of this Problem :

Add this:

```
        dependencies:
      one_context: ^1.1.1
```

---

```
then :
```

---

```
OneNotification<List<Locale>>(
      onVisited: (context, localeList) {
        print('widget visited!');
      },
      stopBubbling: true, // avoid the data bubbling to ancestors widgets
      initialData: _localeEnglish, // [data] is null during boot of the application, but you can set initialData
      rebuildOnNull: true, // Allow other entities reload this widget without messing up currenty data (Data is cached on first event)
      builder: (context, localeList) {
        return MaterialApp(
          supportedLocales: localeList,
        );
      },
    );
```

Here is the [Link](https://pub.dev/packages/one_context) of this Package kindly have a look .